Dell Inspiron 11 3162/3164 not booting - Lbuntu 22.04.4 LTS ISO
I need to post an issue about Lbuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) ISO installation through a pen drive with Etcher, version 1.18.11, for iMac macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
I mounted the Lubuntu on a pen drive with 15 GB capacity. Then I boot from pen drive and start Lubuntu from the pen drive. From these I try to install Lubuntu on hard drive with the option ENCRYP SYSTEM activated.
I see the files of Lubuntu where on the hard drive. There were. I un plug the pen drive and try to start Lubuntu from hard drive, but it doesn't boot. I do not see any message prompting me to decrypt the hard drive. The system does not goes to that step. I do not see the promt screen.
I am going to try to mount version 23.10 instead of version 22.04.4 to check if it works. I do a lot of searching about BIOS options (like activating UEFI on boot), but it does not boot properly.
Thanks in advance
Jose - Madrid

Is this a dual boot (has both Windows and Lubuntu)? Did you use the "Erase disk" option or manual partitioning? Have you unplugged the pen drive from your computer? When you try to boot from the hard drive, do you get a prompt to decrypt the hard drive? If you get a prompt and enter the passphrase do you see anything on the screen? Do you get the login screen? Edit your question and add all these information.

Firstly you were using the stable version of the Lubuntu manual; ie. page for Lubuntu 23.10.  Use https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/1/1.2/booting_the_image.html to view the manual for the LTS or 22.04 release (currently). Did you note where the bootloader was written to?  Was it correct? or did you force it to write in an invalid place (which will mean it won't boot/be-used)?

@user68186 I did not use dual both, just Lubuntu boot. I use Erase disk option. I did unplugged the pen drive when trying to boot from hard disk, so it could boot from hard disk. When i try to boot from hard disk i do not get to the point where the system ask me to put the password to decryt the disk, i don´t know why, so i don´t see the login screen. Hope it gives all the information you need to give me more advised. Thank you for the advised you just give me.

@guiverc I don´t really understand the guidance you were trying to give me. Should i use Llubuntu 23.10 instead of 22.04? I don´t really know how to check where the bootloader was written to? What do you mean about that? I see a GRUB version of bootloader, so Is it what you were asking for? I don´t understand what do you mean about to force the bootloader to write in an invalid place, how could i check i did not did that? Thanks, Jose
